# Script not working but command works outside of script

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting, mysql

I have a very simple script that basically runs a command and then emails the report to a user:

```
#!/bin/bash

FROMDATE=`date -d "last week 13:00 " '+%Y-%m-%d'`
TODATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`
SLOWLOG='/var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log'
REPORT='/home/user/slow.log.'$TODATE
PTQUERY='/usr/bin/pt-query-digest'
SUBJECT="Slow Query Report -- $TODATE"
EMAIL="blah@blah.com"



$PTQUERY --since=\'$FROMDATE\' --until=\'$TODATE\' $SLOWLOG > $REPORT


/usr/bin/mutt -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $REPORT
```

Everything works perfect when I run this manually (below)

```
/usr/bin/pt-query-digest --since='2015-10-21' --until='2015-10-28' /var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log > /home/user/slow.log
```

And if I echo the line in the script:

```
/usr/bin/pt-query-digest --since='2015-10-21' --until='2015-10-28' /var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log
```

When I run the script I get an error

```
Invalid --since value at /usr/bin/pt-query-digest line 13562.
```

So it looks like it could be something with the single quotes?  I'm not sure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're escaping the single quotes in the script, which means they don't get interpreted by the shell. That means that `pt-query-digest` gets the literal string `'2015-10-21'` rather than just the date, `2015-10-21`. `pt-query-digest` presumably does not know what to do with the single quotes.

You should get rid of the escaped single quotes in `--since=\'$FROMDATE\'` and just use double quotes instead. Make sure to modify both uses in that line.